# How do I enable code completion and intellisense for inline CSS in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When working on CSS files in WebStorm, intellisense will operate on both the property name (bringing up a list of possible properties when I start typing) and property values (showing be the possible string values, showing the color when the property is a color selector, etc).

[image]
[image]

When working with React and other libraries/frameworks that prefer CSS to be inlined in the component JavaScript file, I would like to have the same type of code completion. However, when defining a React object with name/value pairs to be used as the value for the style property, WebStorm treats it as a normal JavaScript object, without any CSS-specific information.

[image]

Is there a way to indicate to WebStorm that names correspond to CSS style properties, or that the object itself contains style rules?

Comment: no, there is no way to inject CSS in this code, and WebStorm can't know that this is not a usual javascript but a style definition

Comment: one of the `13 reasons why` you should use VS Code.

Comment: I have this issue also. And there is no completion for Component class with props also.